# php scrape dynamically loaded content via ajax and knockout.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I need to scrape some data from a website which is being loaded via ajax using knockout.js (I don't know exactly on which technology it is working.)

Site is www.msc.com. Here I am searching for schedules like from Barcelona to Miami. So the result is loaded via ajax but doesn't show up in console or firebug.

Ex. When we search a schedule like port of load and port of discharge. Ex. Port of load : Barcelona and port of discharge : Miami. We will get all the ships details loaded below. I want that content to be scraped.

I have tried too many times. Any help or suggestion will be appreciable.

Comment: is this the web api page for that site?  https://dscm.msc.com/ApiMAXS/Help/

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape this using [Phantomjs PHP wrapper](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)